# AngularJS: geolocation + promise + $apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have some problems using the geolocation AngularJS plugin https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation/blob/master/src/geolocation.js.

When you look at line 17, an `$apply` is called. This seems ok for me, because the callback of the `getCurrentPosition` runs async, and out of the scope of angular's digest:

```
angular.module('geolocation')
  .factory('geolocation', ['$q','$rootScope','$window','geolocation_msgs','$timeout',function ($q,$rootScope,$window,geolocation_msgs,$timeout) {
    return {
      getLocation: function (opts) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if ($window.navigator && $window.navigator.geolocation) {
          $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){deferred.resolve(position);});
          }
```

In a normal desktop browser this works fine. But when used inside a PhoneGap app, along with cordovas geolocation plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation), it throws an `$digest already in progress` error on iOS7.

So, I did a little bit of debugging, and found out, that the following version works everywhere, on a desktop browser AND inside a PhoneGap app:

```
angular.module('geolocation')
  .factory('geolocation', ['$q','$rootScope','$window','geolocation_msgs','$timeout',function ($q,$rootScope,$window,geolocation_msgs,$timeout) {
    return {
      getLocation: function (opts) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if ($window.navigator && $window.navigator.geolocation) {
          $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            deferred.resolve(position);
          }
```

So, I'm a little bit confused.

1. Is the whole callback still in angular's scope?
2. If so, why does an `$apply` call don't throw an `$digest already in progress` error on my desktop browser?
3. And if it's not in the scope, why does just a `deferred.resolve(position);` work? Does this have anything to do with references to the `deferred` var?
4. Do I have to wrap the `resolve` call on a promise (and outside of angulars digest scope) inside an `$apply` callback?

Hope someone can help me to clear my mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function(){deferred.resolve(position);});
```

Is incorrect. It should just be:

```
deferred.resolve(position);
```

Since the `deferred` comes from `$q`, it's inside Angulars world. `$q` is aware of the `$rootScope` and will call `$rootScope.$apply()` for you when you resolve a promise. The error you're getting: `$digest already in progress` is a proof of that. Angular is telling you that there's some part of the code which is calling `$apply()` twice, which is line 17.